# How to consolidate various rotation and flip image transformations into the simplest transformation?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can anyone give me some idea on how to solve this problem for use on an iPhone app. Users can rotate and flip image thumbnails but I want to save these transformations so I can apply them to the full size image later. I want to be able to work out the simplest transformation from a string off all transformations applied. I've include some examples below.

flipH+flipV = r180

flipH+flipV+flipH = flipV

flipV+flipH+flipV = flipH

r90CW+flipH+flipV+flipH+r180CCW = flipH+r90CCW

Comment: Why do you think that `r180` is simpler than `flipH+flipV`?

Comment: @sergio - I should point out, I'm a PHP developer and someone else is doing the app for me. I assume you'd do two transformations and two saves with flipH+flipV and only 1 with r180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are worried by the cost of **applying** each transformation in a sequence to your image; as opposed to this, you would like to store a *composed transformation* and apply it just once.

If this is correct, then you can use the methods that are listed under the "Modifying Affine Transformations " section in [CGAffineTransform Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html). I.e., you would start with a basic identity transform:

```
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

then you would apply all of your transform in sequence and build a composed transform:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rotation);
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, dx, dy);
...
```

that you can apply to your image.

EDIT:

Composing 2 transformations means multiplying 2 matrices. If you just compose rotations, you will get a rotation matrix with different values (0s are kept in the same locations); if you compose translation and rotation, then you will get a new matrix with 2 more values (as compared to a rotation matrix). Have a look at [this explanation](http://people.gnome.org/~mathieu/libart/libart-affine-transformation-matrices.html), which is very visual.

Affine transforms are entirely ok for any iOS version (they are really a basic thing), including iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you understand my query. What's the performance like of the composed transformation? Is it similar to running a simple rotation? Is CGAffineTransform OK for ios 5?

Comment: Thanks, that looks ideal. Will get it tested and confirm your answer. Thanks.